# Vibe.d rest interface router wrong path matching

Tags: rest, backend, d, vibed

I'm using vibe.d for my rest API. I have two methods: `addUser` and `getUser`. I used `@path("/api/v3/users/")`, so now the URL should look like this: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/users/user. The **POST** method works fine with this URL, but I can't get the **GET** method to work.
I use the same url (?someParams), but the server responds with **404**. I've noticed, that when I use URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/users/user/user, it says "Unexpected 'u' when converting from type string to type int", but if I put anything else than *user* after the /, it throws 404 again.
I'm sure I must've overlooked some dumb mistake :D

### Interface:

`@path("/api/v3/auth/")
interface IUserAPI
{
    /** Adding a user */
    User addUser(string email, string firstName, string lastName, string password, string locale);
    /** Getting a user by id */
    User getUser(int id);
}`

### Class:

```
/** User API */
class UserAPI : IUserAPI {
    /** Testing user */
    User user;
    /** Adding a user */
    @safe
    User addUser(string email, string firstName, string lastName, string password, string locale) {
        user = User(1, 0, email, firstName, lastName, password, locale, 0, false, "","", 0, "");
        return user;
    }
    /** Getting a user by id */
    @safe
    User getUser(int id) {
        logInfo(id.to!string);
        return user;
    }
}<br>
```

### Registering rest interfaces:

```
router.registerRestInterface(new UserAPI, MethodStyle.camelCase);
router.registerRestInterface(new LogsListAPI, MethodStyle.camelCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I found my answer. When you use **id** as a parameter, then it puts it directly in the URL. Like http://whatever.com/api/1(id)/user.

Comment: Great! I couldn't find this anywhere else!